# Inferring a Typescript function return type based on a type parameter

Tags: typescript, type-inference

What is the difference in terms of type inference between the function types below? Why can the Typescript compiler infer `O[K]` when `O` is a function parameter, but not when `O` is only a type parameter? Is there an alternative approach to typing this kind of signature?

```
interface I {
  x: string;
  y: number;
  z: boolean;
}
type Obj = { [key: string]: any };

declare function f<O extends Obj, K extends keyof O>(obj: O, key: K): O[K];
const obj: I = { x: "bar", y: 5, z: true };
const x = f(obj, "x");
//    ^ has expected type `string` 

declare function g<O extends Obj, K extends keyof O>(key: K): O[K];
const y = g<I>("y");
//          ^ Error: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.

declare function h<O extends Obj, K extends keyof O = keyof O>(key: K): O[K];
const z = h<I>("z");
//    ^ has type `string | number | boolean` instead of `boolean`
```

[TS Playground →](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLIN4ChnIB4BcyAzmFKAOYDcOyAnkSAK4C2ARtDbgF5FsD2-ADYQ4IGgF8sYOgAcUAeTYArZAF5MyANoBrCAxJlKAXSJi6yCTSwATCAiFwoKGExAIwwfiGQwAPArIEHiQIDbEyErKADTIANJBIRBhEXp0-DCRAHwAFPwqRAqxaURxAJSFWnHGNAjepMj5ykToGhj4RABEbE6dsQYArLG8yGRMKFZYdSANeOq%20eSqxnXidZTQA9Bu4uAB6yAAWcBHB8h4QNqNyKAAGpOQgFDfIgLwbgLI7WLb2js6%20bh5eHwUAKJULhSJLeKg5LgtIZbI5ErxCqRKo1Kb1MD0ebA1C5Tp0NabbY7Ul7ZAAUSgUH4UCIFLwZ0glwATFd5MgnBRWMkwMRYmwmFiKPwsQBGAB0nzsDicLn%20nm8hxBwTBESisQSqphqX08MCGjhmQUuSR5Uq1VqmOQ3HmBz8eJynW4RKwW1J%20yOERkHLuRkeyAAPshmOxoEHkAJhKIQM9QKRRJd4TcoyIxDcsEA)

Comment: *"Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1."* - you cannot infer one type parameter while specifying the other.

Comment: Ahhh, that’s interesting — didn’t know that. That would presumably also explain the failure of `K` to be narrowed in the final example because no further inference is done and the default value is used. Not sure I understand why that needs to be the case though.

Comment: Translating the answers to the other questions to this question yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/DmMEVm) code

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! Both of these seem like a pretty bad idea for actual use (at least for my case), but they do help make clear the current restrictions. Fingers crossed for partial type parameter inference at some point in the future.